# Progress Bar with Cycle Divider

Tags: javascript, css, html, divider

I am trying to create a progress bar and I want a cycle divider so that I can divide the situations I have  [image]

Can someone give me a solution ?

Comment: I really don't know if it fits your need, I found the [Splitted Bootstrap ProgressBar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked) which looks like what you needed.

Comment: Yeah exactly I use this but the thing is how to add the cycles. On this cycles can the user to choose a situation

Comment: First you need to know what will interact with your progress bar : is it a file to download, or is it a step-by-step operation like multiple layout forms ?

Comment: The second multiple layout form a step by step operation so then you can go back and fron using this cycles

Comment: I could bring you some help but now you need to bring your HTML code you wrote so far in order to let me know what is missing.

Comment: I have no html code in reality for the progress bar. All the other html code has nothing to do with the functionality of progress bar. If there is a solution for the progress bar then I can attach this solution on my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate your progress bar, see my fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/rnwo4xf2/).

Just add a class `.current` to the `.cycle` you want to be currently highlighted. I used pure CSS on this with floats for better compatibility.

You can add numbers to the circles by adding `.counter` class to the `.progress` element.

```css
.progress, .progress * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.progress {
    width: 410px;
    padding: 15px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #ddd;
}
.progress .cycle {
    width: 90px;
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
}
.progress .cycle:first-of-type {
    width: 0px;
}
.progress .cycle.current ~ .cycle {
    background: #fff;
}
.progress .cycle:after {
    content: '';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    right: -15px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #555;
}
.progress .cycle.current:after {
    background: deepskyblue;
}
.progress .cycle.current ~ .cycle:after {
    background: #fff;
}
/* With Counters */
.progress.counter {
    counter-reset: cycle; 
}
.progress.counter .cycle:after {
    counter-increment: cycle;
    content: counter(cycle);
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
Using Floats
<div class="progress">
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle current"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle current"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="progress counter">
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle current"></div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

---

I also created another demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/rnbftmLb/) using the **CSS3 [flex-box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** approach.

The contents of the .progress element will now adjust according to the width of the element. This gives way to adding more cycles dynamically and adjusting the progress bar width without worrying about fixed widths. Also, this prevents the cycles from wrapping in very compressed widths.

```css
body { font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal;}
.progress, .progress * { box-sizing: border-box; }
.progress {
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 20px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    background: #ddd;
}
.progress .cycle {
    height: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
}
.progress .cycle:first-of-type {
    width: 0px;
    flex: 0 0;
}
.progress .cycle.current ~ .cycle {
    background: #fff;
}
.progress .cycle:after {
    content: '';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    right: -15px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: #555;
}
.progress .cycle.current:after {
    background: deepskyblue;
}
.progress .cycle.current ~ .cycle:after {
    background: #fff;
}
/* With Counters */
.progress.counter {
    counter-reset: cycle; 
}
.progress.counter .cycle:after {
    counter-increment: cycle;
    content: counter(cycle);
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial;
}
/* Fixed Width */
.fixed1 {
    width: 400px;
}
.fixed2 {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Using Flex</h2>
6 cycles (fixed width)
<div class="progress fixed1">
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle current"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 0px;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
9 cycles (100% width)
<div class="progress">
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle current"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
</div>
5 cycles (fixed width, numbered)
<div class="progress counter fixed2">
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle current"></div>
</div>
7 cycles (100%, numbered)
<div class="progress counter">
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle current"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
    <div class="cycle"></div>
</div>
```

The only problem for the CSS3 flexbox approach is browser [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). If the browser support is alright with you, then go for the flex-box approach :)